# eot fonts are not getting affected in my grail applocation

Tags: html, css, grails

This is my bootstrap.min.css

[image]

here is my floder structure

[image]

How do i get these fonts in my gsp?

Answer (score 0):

I have my bootstrap.min.css under css directly and the fonts under the same directories as you. But the paths in my bootstrap.css looks a bit different...:

```
@font-face{font-family:'Glyphicons Halflings';
src:url(../fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot);
src:url(../fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot?#iefix)
```

and in my layout/main.gsp

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="${request.contextPath}/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="${request.contextPath}/css/font-awesome.min.css">
```